# MySql Select inside Select with Operator IN

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance, select

I have 2 tables:

Group

```
+------------+------------+
|  id_group  |  id_user   |
+------------+------------+
| 1          | 1,2,3,4    |
```

User

```
+------------+-----------+
|   id_user  |   name    |
+------------+-----------+
| 1          | james     |
| 2          | lars      |
| 3          | kirk      |
| 4          | robert    |
```

I'd like use this query:

```
select id_group as id, (select name from user where id_user IN (id_user)) as name
from group
where id_group = 1
```

Result:

```
+--------+-------------------------+
|   id   |           name          |
+--------+-------------------------+
| 1      | james,lars,kirk,robert  |
```

Comment: this violates 3rd normal form of a database by having multiple values in 1 column.  Logically one should have a group_users table which links each user to a group.  Is this a design change which can be made or MUST you use your existing structure/layout?

Comment: Does the order of the users in the list matter in relation to the order in table group?   and what data type is "id_user" in your group table?  is it a [SET Type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set.html)?

Comment: @xQbert the order isn't important... id_user in table Group is a varchar... i know they should be foreign keys of table User but I cannot change the existing structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IN wil not work, as id_user from group will be handled as text,  so FIND_IN_SET a better but slow possibility

But you should urgently read [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

> ```
> CREATE TABLE `group` (
>   `id_group` INTEGER,
>   `id_user` VARCHAR(7)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO `group`
>   (`id_group`, `id_user`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', '1,2,3,4');
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE user (
>   `id_user` INTEGER,
>   `name` VARCHAR(6)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO user
>   (`id_user`, `name`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', 'james'),
>   ('2', 'lars'),
>   ('3', 'kirk'),
>   ('4', 'robert'),
>   ('5', 'peter');
> ```

> ```
> select id_group as id
> , (select GROUP_CONCAT(name ORDER BY id_user ASC) from user u where FIND_IN_SET(u.id_user, g.id_user)) as name
> from `group` g
> where id_group = 1
> ```

> ```
> id | name                  
> -: | :---------------------
>  1 | james,lars,kirk,robert
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=95fee7e7fc8911ccc26de2959c55d077)*

Comment: Good catch.  if we use the other example peter shows up

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```sql
SELECT 
    id_group AS id, 
    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(name) FROM user WHERE id_user IN (id_user)) AS name
FROM group
WHERE a.id_group = 1
```

Or

This assumes the string has the initial and final single quotes in them.

```sql
SELECT 
    id_group AS id, 
    (SELECT 
        GROUP_CONCAT(name) 
     FROM user 
     WHERE id_user IN (REPLACE(id_user,  ',', ''','''))
    ) AS name
FROM group
WHERE a.id_group = 1
```

If not, you could just add them.

```sql
SELECT 
    id_group AS id, 
    (SELECT 
        GROUP_CONCAT(name) 
     FROM user 
     WHERE id_user IN ('''' + REPLACE(id_user,  ',', ''',''') + '''')
    ) AS name
FROM group
WHERE id_group = 1
```

Comment: Not sure if it matters but the names list of names generated may not align to the order in the id_user https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4be033b845ade160298d9edaac594b24  Note in my example: James ID is 4 so I would expect him last on the list generated: but it may not matter to the OP.   Also `group` is a reserved word and as a table name would need to be escaped using backtick

Comment: @nayanish I try your example and works if i use inside IN(1,2,3,4) but if i use IN(id_user) not works....I doubt that it cannot be done :(

Comment: @Wall3-8e it works look at the dbfiddle.uk link  in comments.  However that is version 8 of mySQL; and we do not know your version.

Comment: @xQbert Modified the query can you please try again

Comment: @NayanishDamania  adding a.id_user in your top query is wrong.  it worked before just not with order and since order  isn't important:  Id' stick with your original: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5b76f3fbe896d2befae9edbb8fbfcf38  but again it depends on RDBMS version.  works in 8 not in 5.6  *note I had to escape the 'Group' keyword in the linked demo

Comment: @xQbert I have seen that the example works... my system use MariaDb... it only takes the first name like second example https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5b76f3fbe896d2befae9edbb8fbfcf38 ... do you know why?

Comment: Id use the find_In_set approach.  This approach doesn't handle the where clause by group.  As to why this isn't working, I'd have to research.  The `find_in_set` approach seems correct to me .